# Common equation of Polar coordinates

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

A conic touches the ellipse $1/r=1+e\cos\theta$ at the point $\theta$= α. They have a common focus at the pole and have the same eccentricity. Show that the length of the latus rectum is
$$\frac{2l(1-e^2)}{e^2+2e\cos\alpha+1}$$

**My attempt:**
Since they have the same focus and they touch each other at $\theta=\alpha$ then equation of the tangent for the conic section at alpha will be $l/r =e\cos\theta+\cos(\theta-\alpha)$ and equation of the tangent for the ellipse will be $l/r =e\cos\theta+\cos(\theta-\alpha)${equation of ellipse is $l/r=1+e\cos\theta$}.

Am I on the correct path? What will be my next step? I have to prove that length of latus rectum is $\frac{2l(1-a^2)}{e^2+2e\cos\alpha+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

If $P$ is the tangency points of the ellipses, then the normal at $P$ must be the same for both ellipses, and this is also the bisector of the angle of vertex $P$ subtending the foci. As the ellipses have a focus ($F$) in common, that means that the other foci ($G$ and $H$ in figure below) must be aligned with $P$.

But the ellipses are also similar (because they have the same eccentricity), hence triangles $FPG$ and $FPH$ are similar and:
$$
PH:PF=PF:PG.
$$
From that, it is not difficult to find the required expression for the latus rectum $2l'$ of the second ellipse. Setting: $2a=PF+PG$, $2a'=PF+PH$, $r=PF$, from the above proportion one gets:
$$
2a'={2ar\over2a-r}.
$$
Hence:
$$
2l'=(1-e^2)2a'=(1-e^2){2ar\over2a-r}.
$$
Inserting here $a=l/(1-e^2)$ and $r=l/(1+e\cos\alpha)$ one gets the desired result.

[image]

Comment: But in question it is not clear that the other conic is ellipse or else so how can you draw 2 ellipse

Comment: @user1155953 If "they have the same eccentricity" then they must be the same type of conic.